# Clarification about Integers forming a Ring

Tags: ring-theory, abelian-groups, integers

I was reading through Quaternions for Computer Graphics by Dr. John Vince and at page 10, he defined a ring as a set with a binary operation that forms an abelian group under addition and multiplication with additional distributive properties. Right after such definition, he stated that the set of integers form a ring. However, earlier, at page 9, he clearly stated that the integers DO NOT form a group under multiplication. Well then, how does the integers form an abelian group under multiplication when it does not even form a group under such binary operation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would say to double check his definition of a ring. It would be highly nonstandard to require a ring to form a group under multiplication (or  for it's nonzero elements to form a group under multiplication). Usually you require all of the axioms for an abelian group EXCEPT: you don't require multiplicative inverses to exist.

Comment: The book is wrong on that point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will quote a phrase from the book: "A ring is formally defined as a system where (S, +) and (S, ×) are abelian groups and the distributive axioms." I am aware of the ring of integers being defined as "lacking of multiplicative inverse" but no where in his book did he mentioned anything like that. I tried to search for any errata of some sort but I didn't find anything addressing such issue.

Comment: Well, it is an error, moreover, the author would immediately recognize it as such since it contradicts the example already given.

Comment: Also, for rings, the multiplication need not be commutative.

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of a [ring with unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Definition), requires that the multiplication is associative and have a neutral element (the unit element) and is distributive over the addition (that forms an abelian group). But the existence of an inverse and the commutativity of multiplication are not required.

The integers $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual addition and multiplication are the classical example of a ring.

If any element of the ring has  an inverse with respect to the multiplication we say that it is a **division** ring. An example is the ring of invertible matrices with $n\times n$ entries in a field under the usual addition and multiplications for matrices.